# Let $V $be a vector space. Prove/Disprove: There is a norm $\|\cdot\|$, such that all subsets of $V$ are open sets in $(V,\|\cdot\|)$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

The Assignment:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with $V \not= \{0\}$. Prove or disprove:
>
> There is a norm $\|\cdot\|_d$ on $V$, such that all subsets of $V$ are open sets in $(V,\|\cdot\|)$.

I have read about topologies which are discrete, but I don't know how to define the norm such that the property is fulfilled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A different hint: can $\{0\}$  be open with respect to a norm?

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** This is impossible. Show that there is a homeomorphism between a $1$-dimensional subspace and $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The fastest answerer in the West.

Comment: Could elaborate further? I know what a homomorphism is, but I don't see the connection to the assignment.

Comment: @KitKat: I could. But I prefer that you think about it for a little more than two minutes, and figure it out for yourself.

Comment: @Neal: Perhaps the sleepless-iest answerer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Instead of explaining me the solution, could you maybe firstly explain why there is not such a norm? I have trouble visualising why it doesn't work.

Comment: @KitKat: I have explained. Think about the hint for a little bit. Is it possible that *all* sets are open, and there is a subspace which is *homeomorphic* to $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Neal I would say Mideast instead... but actually with Internet cardinal points are less relevant.

Answer (score 3):

**Yet another hint:** All norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent (Note: It 's true only when the vector space is finite dimensional) and thus generates the same topology. Thus one need only consider the standard norm on $\mathbb R^n$ and check whether the topology is discrete.

Comment: It's a nice hint, but it might bit misleading, because there's a gap from an arbitrary vector space to a finite dimensional vector space (and so it ends up being similar to my hint).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Indeed. Might be I should write down that explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x\in V$, $x\ne0$. What can you say about the sequence
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n}x\qquad(n\ge1)
$$
by considering the sequence $(\|x_n\|)_{n\ge1}$?